# Find by date without function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection with a date property. I need to find some objects that has a date greater than a **literal date string**. I'm using node.js native driver. And I receive the date as string. When I try this, doesn't work:

```
db.myCollection.find({ 
        'dateField': { $gte : "1974-11-18T02:00:00.000Z"  }
}).count()
```

This doesn't work too:

```
db.myCollection.find({ 
        'dateField': { $gte : {$date: '1974-11-18T02:00:00.000Z'}  }
}).count()
```

But this works:

```
db.myCollection.find({ 
        'dateField: { $gte : ISODate("1974-11-18T02:00:00.000Z")  }
}).count()
```

How can I query a mongodb by date without use Date() or ISODate() functions?

**Edit:**

I can't use function because on my nodejs app I have this object:

```
let conditions = {}
conditions['dateField'] = "1974-11-18T02:00:00.000Z"

let rows = await db.collection('myCollection').aggregate([
    {$match: conditions},
    {$count: "total"}
]).toArray()
```

So I can't pass a "function" on conditions object to $match on mongodb, because this doesn't work:

```
conditions['dateField'] = new Date("1974-11-18T02:00:00.000Z")
```

Comment: do you have any specific reason not to use the `Date()` function ? since you are trying to find the ones only greater than the provided date, you must convert the string to date in order compare

Comment: Please see my Edit

Comment: It's not clear to me why you can't use `conditions['dateField'] = new Date("1974-11-18T02:00:00.000Z")`

Comment: I can use like that. It's more difficult for me because I need to deep search on my object (my query is daynamic, so I need to find all dates and then do a "replace"). I receive a JSON from my client app (where I build the query) and the JSON doesn't acept functions. So I was looking for a way to compare date on mongo with dates in literal string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by **changing my mongodb field from date type to string**. But the string **needs to be on ISO-8601** date format like "1974-11-18T02:00:00.000Z". Now I can query on mongodb using date in literal string:

```
db.myCollection.find({ 
    'dateField': { $gte : "1974-11-18T02:00:00.000Z"  }
}).count()
```

I think this works because mongodb should understand that the string is in ISO format and then deserializes the string on date to make the comparison